# How can I put something under something in a Tree?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree, forest

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=32pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.No1Feng ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to break `No1Feng` in to two lines with `No1` and `Feng`?

Comment: Why is this tagged `forest` when it uses `tikz-qtree`? The code you posted produces nothing like the output you posted.

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted does not draw branches in the way your output shows. It also does not use `forest`.

However, whichever kind of branches you desire, and whichever package you use to produce them, you need to create a multiline node. As usual for TiKZ nodes, setting an alignment using `align=` enables this option. You can then insert line breaks as required.

Here, I show how to adapt your code to produce a tree with a line break as indicated (but the branches are as specified in your code - not as shown in your alleged output), and how to do so in `forest` (with branches as shown in your output, as well as a line break in the specified node).

```
\documentclass[multi,varwidth,tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=32pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west, align=left}}
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.{No1\\Feng} ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, thick, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=west,
    align=left,
    base=b,
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier=tier #1}{level()}
  }
    [S
    [NP
      [Det
        [the]
      ]
      [N
        [cat]
      ]
    ]
      [VP
        [No1\\Feng
        ]
        [PP
          [P
            [on]
          ]
          [NP
            [Det
              [the]
            ]
            [N
              [mat]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}  

\end{document}
```

First tree:

[image: tikz-qtree tree]

Second tree:

[image: forest tree]

Answer (score 1):

The regular techniques used to allow line breaks inside nodes can be adopted here also since the tree uses nodes to hold the contents. I have used `\begin{scope}[text width=\widthof{Feng}]` and then we can break lines with regular `\\` like `[.No1\\Feng ]`
You can also use `align=left` instead of `text width`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
-- +(8pt,0)
|- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=4.5em}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\begin{scope}[text width=\widthof{Feng}]  %%<--- this
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.No1\\Feng ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]